# C 11 error: ‘X’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I'm getting the following errors in my code, and I'm unsure why since 'socketfd' is declared in client.hpp and is used in the constructor within client.cpp but then when I try and use it later I am getting an error.

Terminal output:

```
g++ client.cpp -o client.o -pthread -c -std=c++11
client.cpp: In function ‘void sendMessage(std::string)’:
client.cpp:37:23: error: ‘socketfd’ was not declared in this scope
```

client.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

class Client {

    public:
        Client();
        ~Client();
        void sendMessage(std::string);

    private:
        int status, socketfd;
        struct addrinfo host_info;
        struct addrinfo *host_info_list;

};
```

client.cpp

```
#include "client.hpp"


Client::Client() {
    memset(&host_info, 0, sizeof host_info);
    std::cout << "Setting up the structs..." << std::endl;
    host_info.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    host_info.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    status = getaddrinfo("192.168.1.3", "8888", &host_info, &host_info_list);
    if (status != 0) {
        std::cout << "getaddrinfo error " << gai_strerror(status);
    }

    std:: cout << "Creating a socket..." << std::endl;
    socketfd = socket(host_info_list->ai_family, host_info_list->ai_socktype, host_info_list->ai_protocol);
    if (socketfd == -1) {
        std::cout << "Socket Errror ";
    }
    std::cout << "Connecting..." << std::endl;
    status = connect(socketfd, host_info_list->ai_addr, host_info_list->ai_addrlen);
    if (status == -1) {
        std::cout << "Connect Error" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Successfully Connected" << std::endl;
}

Client::~Client() {

}

void sendMessage(std::string msg) {
    std::cout << "Sending Message: " << msg << std::endl;
    int len;
    ssize_t bytes_sent;
    len = strlen(msg.c_str());
    bytes_sent = send(socketfd, msg.c_str(), len, 0);
}
```

This is some of the first C++ I've done, and I'm a bit confused why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing `Client::` before `sendMessage()`:

```
void Client::sendMessage(std::string msg) {
     ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 4):

The function signature of `sendMessage` is not that of a member function. Try this-:

```
  void Client::sendMessage(std::string msg) {
```